# Rhadoop mapreduce for multiple input files

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, rhadoop

I'm building a mapreduce program, using R, that extracts the relevant features from a set of features in a dataset using genetic algorithm. I need to put many files as an input to my mapreduce job. My code below is my mapreduce program but it works only for one input file (data.csv).

```
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(rmr2)
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="/home/rania/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop")
Sys.getenv("HADOOP_CMD")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING="/home/rania/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar")
library(rhdfs)
hdfs.init()
rmr.options(backend = "hadoop")
hdfs.mkdir("/user/rania/genetic")
hdfs.mkdir("/user/rania/genetic/data")
```

I put my files in one folder in hdfs

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/rania/Downloads/matrices/*.csv /user/rania/genetic/data/
```

This is the map function

```
mon.map <- function(.,data){ 
data <- read.csv("/home/rania/Downloads/dataset.csv", header = T, sep = ";")
y <- c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)

ga_ctrl <- gafsControl(functions = rfGA, # Assess fitness with RF
                       method = "cv")   # 10 fold cross validation
set.seed(10)
lev <- c("1","0")
rf_ga3 <- gafs(x = data, y = y,
                           iters = 10, # 100 generations of algorithm
                           popSize = 4, # population size for each generation
                           levels = lev,
                           gafsControl = ga_ctrl)
keyval(rf_ga3$ga$final, data[names(data) %in% rf_ga3$ga$final]  ) 
 }
```

This is the reduce function

```
mon.reduce <- function(k,v){
keyval(k,v) }
```

Now i apply the mapreduce job

```
hdfs.root = 'genetic' 
hdfs.data = file.path(hdfs.root, 'data')
hdfs.out = file.path(hdfs.root, 'out')
csv.format <- make.output.format("csv")
genetic = function (input, output) {mapreduce(input=input, output=output, input.format="csv",output.format=csv.format, map=mon.map,reduce=mon.reduce)}
out = genetic(hdfs.data, hdfs.out)
```

Then we print the result from hdfs

```
results <- from.dfs(out, format="csv")
print(results)
```

OR

```
hdfs.cat("/genetic/out/part-00000")
```

I tried to change the map function to make it work for many files but it failed

```
mon.map <- function(.,data){ 
data <- list.files(path="/home/rania/Downloads/matrices/", full.names=TRUE, pattern="\\.csv") %>% lapply(read.csv, header=TRUE, sep=",") 
y <- c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)
for (i in 1:4){
ga_ctrl <- gafsControl(functions = rfGA, # Assess fitness with RF
                       method = "cv")   # 10 fold cross validation
set.seed(10)
lev <- c("1","0")
rf_ga3 <- gafs(x = data[[i]], y = y,
                           iters = 10, # 100 generations of algorithm
                           popSize = 4, # population size for each generation
                           levels = lev,
                           gafsControl = ga_ctrl)
               }
keyval(rf_ga3$ga$final, do.call(cbind, Map(`[`, data, c(rf_ga3$ga$final)))  )  
 }
```

what can i change in the previous map function to make it work for many input files? thanks

Comment: I think "*.csv" should be used in the pattern argument. Hadoop handles file path patterns easily.

Comment: This is the error : `Error in if (nrow(x) != length(y)) stop("there should be the same number of samples in x and y) : 
  argument is of length zero` , but if i check the rows number of each data[[i]] and the lenghth of y , i found it the same . What could be wrong ? @user238607